# Passive voice sentences

Tags: difference, passive-voice

> I think the question ***that was given to me*** is just about using an easier way.
>
> I think the question ***I was given*** is just about using an easier way.

My question is: Are there any differences in grammar between the two sentence with passive voice or they are similar to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] *I think the question* [*that was given to me*] *is just about using an*
>   *easier way*.
>
> [2] *I think the question* [*that I was given*] *is just about using an*
>   *easier way*.

They have the same meaning but slightly different grammar.

In both examples, the bracketed relative clause modifies “question”.

The difference is that in [1] the recipient of the question is expressed by the PP “to me”, while in [2] by the subject “I”.

Both examples are ‘short’ passives, i.e. an agent *by*-phrase is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

> **Somebody gave me that**

The above sentence is in active voice.

The structure is Subject + verb + indirect object + direct object.

When there are two objects , you can make any one of them a subject.

So the two passive  voice sentences are:

**I was given that**
 or 
.

**That was given to me**

There is no difference in meaning but **I was given  that** is  natural

Comment: "That was given to me" is more clear and anyone can understand its meaning easily in comparison to "I was given that"

Comment: The natural way is to start with a personal  pronoun .It may be difficult  for  you.